# What caused my NDIS miniport driver crashed on XP OS

Tags: ndis, miniport

I wrote a simple packet filter driver based on the example 'passthru' of the Windows DDK, when I turned on the filter function, the OS is crashed and I got the following message from the WinDbg:

> Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 X86 Copyright (c)
>   Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading Dump File [D:\iCheckTool\dump\MEMORY.DMP] Kernel Summary Dump
>   File: Only kernel address space is available
>
> WARNING: Whitespace at start of path element Symbol search path is:
>   D:\iCheckTool\dump;
>   SRV*E:\DebuggingSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;SRV*C:\MyLocalSymbols*http://192.168.20.25/zfprisymbols/
>   Executable search path is:  Windows XP Kernel Version 2600 (Service
>   Pack 3) MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible Product: WinNt, suite:
>   TerminalServer SingleUserTS Built by: 2600.xpsp_sp3_qfe.120504-1617
>   Machine Name: Kernel base = 0x804d8000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0x8055e720
>   Debug session time: Tue Sep 11 09:41:02.828 2012 (UTC + 8:00) System
>   Uptime: 0 days 0:02:30.578 Loading Kernel Symbols
>   ...............................................................
>   ............................................................. Loading
>   User Symbols PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 7ffd800c).  Type ".hh
>   dbgerr001" for details Loading unloaded module list ........
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.
>
> BugCheck C5, {4, 2, 1, 8054c10f}
>
> Probably caused by : Pool_Corruption ( nt!ExDeferredFreePool+109 )
>
> ### Followup: Pool_corruption
>
> 1: kd> !analyze -v
>
> ---
>
> - *
> - Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
> - *
>
>   ---
>
> DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL (c5) An attempt was made to access a pageable
>   (or completely invalid) address at an interrupt request level (IRQL)
>   that is too high.  This is caused by drivers that have corrupted the
>   system pool.  Run the driver verifier against any new (or suspect)
>   drivers, and if that doesn't turn up the culprit, then use gflags to
>   enable special pool. Arguments: Arg1: 00000004, memory referenced
>   Arg2: 00000002, IRQL Arg3: 00000001, value 0 = read operation, 1 =
>   write operation Arg4: 8054c10f, address which referenced memory
>
> ### Debugging Details:
>
> BUGCHECK_STR:  0xC5_2
>
> CURRENT_IRQL:  2
>
> FAULTING_IP:  nt!ExDeferredFreePool+109 8054c10f 895f04          mov
>   dword ptr [edi+4],ebx
>
> DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  DRIVER_FAULT
>
> PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe
>
> TRAP_FRAME:  b42555dc -- (.trap 0xffffffffb42555dc) ErrCode = 00000002
>   eax=89cc1c60 ebx=89e4ded8 ecx=000001ff edx=89cc2a78 esi=80565d20
>   edi=00000000 eip=8054c10f esp=b4255650 ebp=b4255690 iopl=0         nv
>   up ei ng nz ac pe cy cs=0008  ss=0010  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=0030 
>   gs=0000             efl=00010297 nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x109: 8054c10f
>   895f04          mov     dword ptr [edi+4],ebx
>   ds:0023:00000004=???????? Resetting default scope
>
> LOCK_ADDRESS:  8055c4e0 -- (!locks 8055c4e0)
>
> Resource @ nt!PiEngineLock (0x8055c4e0)    Available
>       Contention Count = 1 1 total locks
>
> PNP_TRIAGE:   Lock address  : 0x8055c4e0  Thread Count  : 0   Thread
>   address: 0x00000000   Thread wait   : 0x0
>
> LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 8054c10f to 80545768
>
> STACK_TEXT:   b42555dc 8054c10f badb0d00 89cc2a78 b8338538
>   nt!KiTrap0E+0x238 b4255690 8054c75f 00000001 8055c100 00020019
>   nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x109 b42556d0 8058635e 899522e8 00000000
>   b42557d8 nt!ExFreePoolWithTag+0x47f b42556fc 805878b8 c0000023
>   00000007 8058758c nt!PiGetDeviceRegistryProperty+0x108 b425578c
>   bf879f40 8a523030 00000001 00000100 nt!IoGetDeviceProperty+0x25e
>   b42558f8 bf879735 00000000 e1b5e008 00000000
>   win32k!DrvEnumDisplayDevices+0x33b b425591c 8054268c 00000000 00000000
>   0007ecc4 win32k!NtUserEnumDisplayDevices+0x7c b425591c 7c92e514
>   00000000 00000000 0007ecc4 nt!KiFastCallEntry+0xfc WARNING: Frame IP
>   not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong. 0007f010
>   00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x7c92e514
>
> STACK_COMMAND:  kb
>
> FOLLOWUP_IP:  nt!ExDeferredFreePool+109 8054c10f 895f04          mov
>   dword ptr [edi+4],ebx
>
> SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  1
>
> SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!ExDeferredFreePool+109
>
> FOLLOWUP_NAME:  Pool_corruption
>
> IMAGE_NAME:  Pool_Corruption
>
> DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0
>
> MODULE_NAME: Pool_Corruption
>
> FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xC5_2_nt!ExDeferredFreePool+109
>
> BUCKET_ID:  0xC5_2_nt!ExDeferredFreePool+109
>
> ### Followup: Pool_corruption

Can someone tell me what caused this problem and how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you tried to write into invalid memory region (address = 0x4). Beyond this the debugger analysis you posted isn't too helpful. You can try finding your driver stack (which is not present in your posted debug output) in the debugger to get the failing code, but it's not guaranteed. Other methods to attack this include adding debug prints to your code and capturing it with DbgView (you can later extract them from the memory dump). And you can also connect kernel debugger and catch the error when it happens.